# Displaying a custom dialog when the user exits the browser?

Tags: javascript, dialog, onbeforeunload

**Yes, I realize this is horrible UI and bad accessibility wise, but I am forced to seek out the options due to contracted work ( to which I didn't initially agree upon and am stuck with ).**

**I know that you can assign an event handler to `onbeforeunload` like:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

That would bring about a dialog generated by the OS/browser which cannot be customized. It would ask you to Cancel your request or go on.

So far it seems the only way I can display any custom-ness is by inserting a `window.open` in that event handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     var x = window.open('modal.html');
}
```

This would most likely get blocked by any modern browser as a "popup". I have to display an entirely new page with my dialog, but this seems to be the only way to meet the demand.

**Is this pretty much the only option I have? Other than forcefully telling the client it isn't recommended to do this?**

The only other option would be relying on the user to hit "Cancel request" and then insert the dialog.

Questions I have **already** looked at:

- [jQuery UI Dialog OnBeforeUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889404/jquery-ui-dialog-onbeforeunload)
- [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went the `window.open` route onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 1):

As per the questions you already looked at, you cannot customize that dialog beyond passing in a string message to be displayed by the browser.

[window.onbeforeunload - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Answer (score -1):

you could use a hidden Flash .swf that you reveal at onbeforeunload time instead of window.open

Comment: how would it stay open though? it's just an embed/object element?