# Prevent window closing with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to prevent a browser window closing using jQuery? I've tried this:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
   $(window).unload(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Not closing");
   });
});
```

The alert works but the window closes anyway.

Comment: jQuery also makes sandwiches - inTheKitchen()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible!

You can show a confirmation dialog using `onbeforeunload` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256919/displaying-a-custom-dialog-when-the-user-exits-the-browser) for how to do it), giving the user the choice to not leave the page after all. But you can't prevent the closing against the user's will.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a huge security issue and while I haven't ever needed to investigate it personally, I doubt any browser would allow you to prevent the window from closing.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would be a fundamental breach of the user's autonomy.! How would you like it if a website were to forbid you from closing your browser?

Your best bet is just to display a confirmation dialogue, as Pekka suggests; you can ask them if they're sure, but ultimately its their decision if they want to close it!

Comment: There are legitimate reasons that you would want to prevent a window from closing.  For instance, StackOverflow warns you before closing a window while typing a question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

as other answers say it's not possible to prevent it but you can give the user the opportunity to choose by himself. Maybe you're looking for this...

[How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)