# Is there any way to prevent the browser closing after clicking on the "Close" button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, dom-events

My requirement is as follows:

When the User clicks the `close` button on the browser in a page, the `customized popup` window will appear.
I had designed the `popup` window and I can open that window with the following code:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            openwindow(200, 100, 'Close.aspx');
        };
```

But my ultimate requirement is that the main parent window should not be closed after clicking `any` buttons on the popup window. I don't want the browser's default alert return message window and I am displaying the popup window here instead of browser's default alert window. Is there way to stop the browser closing..?

Comment: I can't see any ethical reason for trapping someone on your website.

Comment: @Charlie, My requirement is like that, that is, two buttons `save` and `send` are present in the popup window. If any unsaved changes in the `parent window` when clicking the `close` button on the browser, the `popup window` alerts and make the user to save. Similarly the `send` button functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to security reasons this is not possible!

You can show a confirmation dialog using `onbeforeunload` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256919/displaying-a-custom-dialog-when-the-user-exits-the-browser) for how to do it), giving the user the choice to not leave the page after all. But you can't prevent the closing against the user's will.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```