# How to get window onbeforeload to always run?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a static dictionary style counter that decrements when a user leaves a page. I can hit F5 or Crtl-F5 in a browser like Firefox and it Decrements fine.

However, if I spam crtl-F5 then the decrement operation does not take place. Maybe the page is refreshing faster than the javascript can load.

Is there any way around this? The code below runs when a user leaves the page.

I should mention that I am incrementing in the page_load event (asp.net)

```
 // decrement
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    var request = {
        "channelId": channelId
    };

    // needed for ie7
    var params = $.toJSON(request);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Live.aspx/Decrement",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"           
    });
}
```

Comment: you should force that request to be syncronized, `async: false`

Comment: FYI.. window.onbeforeunload never works on Opera.

Comment: @jAndy - updated, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @chobo: well I don't know how "hard" you spam, but this code should be at the very top of your html document. So basically `<html><head><script>...dat code</script></head></html>`.

Comment: The page gets incremented before the html is even displayed, so that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe try doing it the "jQuery" way?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889404/jquery-ui-dialog-onbeforeunload#answer-1889450

Comment: Yup, I have to increment and decrement in Jquery and it works

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing and decrementing in Jquery worked