# Saving data in the database if the user leaves the current web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to save the data of the current web page to the database if the user leaves this. How can I achieve this? 
I'm using Ruby on Rails for the backend.

Comment: There is no event handler for when the user leaves the page. See here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026152/how-to-detect-if-a-user-leaves-a-page-in-php

Comment: This seems like something that your analytics service should handle.  As AyexeM mentioned, I don't think there is a way to do it with rails.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.

What I would do is save each field on the blur event something like this

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  $("form.form_class").submit();
});
```

I am thinking that you would have to just update where the form submits to so you dont create a new record on when you are on the new page.

you can see an example of [blur here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_focus_blur)