# Click event not reacting on links

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup an event function to react on clicked links in a menu, but unfortunately its not working.

This is JS code:

```
$('#menu a').click(function() {
    return "Do you really want to leave now?";
});
```

And the HTML bit:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#"> Link1 </a>
    <a href="#"> Link2 </a>
</div>
```

It seems quite straight forward, but unfortunately not working.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kdvk3/6/

Comment: `<a/>` should be `</a>`.

Comment: Jai, fixed that in the fiddle aswell. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result?  Are you trying to pop-up an alert or confirm dialog?

Comment: @MikeBrant, that was my objective yes.

Comment: Your JS fiddle also needs to have jQuery selected as the library to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need you use an `alert()` or `confirm()`, like this:

```
$('#menu a').click(function() {
    return confirm("Do you really want to leave now?");
});
```

Comment: Normally i use `return "Do you really want to leave now?";` to create the popup alert automagically. Why is it not possible in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know how this would work auto-magically. I would be interested in understanding if you are using some kind of custom javascript that would do such a thing.

Comment: I got it working prior to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4041753/531203, but it did not work in this scenario where im not using bind. Simply using jQuery.