# catch 'leave this page' event in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My problem is, when user clicks the close browser/current-tab some cookies need to be deleted.

using jquery, `onbeforeunload`fired and showing **Leave this page** and **Stay on this page**.

How to get which button clicked by user?

how to delete the cookie?

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is not provided by jQuery. You should add the JavaScript tag as well.

Comment: [javascript before leaving the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page) - can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it return a string, it's "true".

The question has already been answered here :

[jQuery UI Dialog OnBeforeUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889404/jquery-ui-dialog-onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {  
       return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }); 


    $(window).unload(function(){
      // do something..
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sessionStorage you can help?
The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the browser window.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp