# exit events with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alert when browser window closed accidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244535/alert-when-browser-window-closed-accidentally)

When a user clicks the browser's exit button(in a sense X) I want to open a new window.

For example, The Wordpress Admin Panel:
If you are in a Wordpress panel and you want to exit, wordpress opens a new window and asks a question.

I would like to do the same.

How can i achieve this?

EDIT:

But don't exit after click.
for example: www.serkanismygirl.com

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1244535/158014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [unload()][1] from jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   //Do your call
   alert('before unload');
  });
```

EDIT - to show yes/no you should use confirm()

Comment: how can i show choice as no/yes ?

Comment: You should use confirm()

Comment: i want to if user exit alerted text even so not exit..
For example: www.serkanismygirl.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery the code will be something like following

```
$(window).unload( function () { 

window.open('http://YOUR_WORDPRESS_URL.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes,
location=yes');

} );
```

Comment: i want to if user exit alerted text even so not exit.. For example: www.serkanismygirl.com