# Disable reload and f5 on my php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timer

i am using a timer on my php page but when some refresh the page the timer start from begin.
i want to disable f5 or reload option on my php page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not (and should not be) possible.

Comment: so how can i prevent my timer to start from begining when my page is reload

Comment: Save the timer's state in `onbeforeunload` and restore it in `onload`.

Comment: please provide me some example

Comment: at best you could maybe store the timer's current value in a cookie and check on each timer tick. but you can **NOT** prevent a user from reloading/refreshing a page in THEIR browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I test it and it works.

```
function disable_f5(e)
{
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116)
  {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("keydown", disable_f5);    
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's work but it's only disable F5. How about CTRL + R, and right click -> click reload icon?

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done – that behaviour is controlled by the end user, and rightly so!

The nearest thing you can do is to display a warning when the window is closed or refreshed, which the user can either decide to heed your warning and stick with the current page, or ignore your request and close/refresh anyway.

See here: [Alert when browser window closed accidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244535/alert-when-browser-window-closed-accidentally)

Comment: Also, the fact that your page was generated with PHP is irrelevant. PHP (a server-side scripting language) generates text output from the server, usually outputting client-side languages such as HTML and Javascript. It's the output from the server that's important here, not how it's generated. I hope that helps!

Comment: so any other option to prevent my time to start with begining when page reload

Comment: You could store the timer info in a session cookie so that if the user refreshes the page (or even leaves then comes back) then the timer remains. But that's another question altogether!

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to disable such browser functionality. Would you like it if a page disabled your F5 key? I doubt it. If you are trying to implement some kind of security here, I suggest looking at proper server-side verification approaches.