# How to catch get request event?

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't work:

```
$(window.document.location).change(function (){

});
```

How do I know when to start sending data back to the server?

UPD: Yes, i want to detect when the user leaves or refresh current page.
Thanks! A window.onbeforeunload what I was looking for.

Comment: what do you think `window.document.location` is an `object` or `string`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to detect when the user leaves the current page?

Comment: May be these answers will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-page-with-unsaved-changes and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244535/alert-when-browser-window-closed-accidentally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If @adrianp is right, you should use [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Comment: Still, this is not always reliable; OP's question is not very clear, but the best option is usually to send the data as soon as you have it.

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps, with a smallish delay to reduce the server load/traffic. This is what e.g. Google apps do. onbeforeunload is mostly used to avoid losing entered data (e.g. an unfinished StackOverflow answer :))

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for a location change (there is for hash change though, see "hashchange"), so you would have to use polling to keep track of the location by checking in intervals.

You could track clicks on anchors inside your page and prevent the default behaviour occuring (i.e. the browser loading the new page and possibly halt executing the remaining JavaScript in the event handler) so you can delay the page change and execute whatever logic your application requires before the document is unloaded (which would fire an unload event).

Which brings me to the question : what do you intend to do ?

Comment: `document.location` returns a `location` object, not a string. It does not offer a `change` event though.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly assumed the "href" property was referenced =)